# How to use a TextBox to search for a record in a MS Access file and display the results?

Tags: asp.net, database-connection, webmatrix

I am using Microsoft ASP.NET web matrix

I have data table called `result` in MS Access. The name of access file is "roll number".

The table consists of following columns:

```
Roll number, name,
subject 1, subject 2, subject 3, subject 4, subject 5,
total marks, result
```

I want that when a user will enter a "roll number" in some textbox and clicks a "submit" button, he is redirected to page showing his results: `roll number`, `name`, `subject 1..5`, `total marks` and `result`.

I want it to be two pages like this:

```
result.aspx          -- where user enters his roll number and submits it

displayresults.aspx  -- where a result is displayed like this:

                        ROLL NUMBER :  (what user entered, looked up in MS Access)
                        NAME :    ("name" read from record from MSAccess file)
                        SUBJECT
                             1 : (mark from "Subject1")
                             2 : (mark from "Subject2")
                             3 : (mark from "Subject3")
                             4 : (mark from "Subject4")
                             5 : (mark from "Subject5")
                        TOTAL MARKS (likewise)
                        RESULT (i.e. PASS/FAIL, as usual, from MSAccess)
```

How to connect such search engine with data kept in a table from an MS Access database?

Please give complete code to generate the web files.

Comment: I tried to understand as much as possible from your question. I think I have preserved 90% of your original thoughts and strived to make them readable and comprehensible. However, I had to fill some gaps where I was unable to see through the original mist. Please review the question after my changes, and feel free to re-edit it and add more details or corrections in case I understood something wrong.

Comment: However, please note that your last request ("please write me the code I need") will probably result in you being scolded upon. You should fetch an ASP.Net tutorial, read it, and simply try to write it yourself.

Comment: have already prepared result.aspx page with a text box and submit button but since I am finding it difficult as to how to link it with access database , I had no other choice than asking for a complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I will not repeat what tutorials say. I will not provide you "the code", as it is mostly trivial, and about any database-querying ASP.NET tutorial will show you how to have a 'textbox that searches for something in a database".

I will only tell you the nontrivial bits:

- firstly, the MS Access file is not just a file, it can be seen as a database. With some typical tools provided by the .Net or ASP frameworks you will be able to send simple `SELECT` SQL queries to that database and it will respond with results. How? -> tutorial.
- most of the tutorials will teach you how to use databases in a "general way"; Tutorials usually does not really care about what database you would like to use. Most of them will will use **connectionstrings** pointing to a `(localdb\v11.0)`(or similar), `.\sqlexpress`, `sqlserver`, 'localhost', '.' or similar things. This is NOT your case. For working with MS Access **files** you have to provide a proper OLEDB connection string that will point exactly to that file. Please see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254500.aspx) and look into "OleDB Connection Strings" section. In very short, the connstring should look like:

  ```
  Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\MyPathToMyDatabase\TheFILE.mdb
  ```
- after you set up the connection string, you may query the database with any tool you like, be it raw `SqlClient`, `SqlDataSource`, `LINQ` or etc.
- actually, when speakin about SqlDataSource, ASP.Net even provides you an `AccessDataSource`. [go figure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163862.aspx)..